# How do I remove the text underline (that I set myself) from a <span> on hover?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to have a link but I want to have a jQuery event fire onclick so I am using a `<span>` with an id instead of a link so I can listen for the click event.

I want to make the `<span>` look like a link so:

1. The cursor should show a hand when the `<span>` is hovered
2. The `<span>` should be underlined and blue

This works fine in CSS, but I want to remove the underline when I hover. How would I do this in CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
span:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> "i want to have a link but i want to have jquery event fire onclick so i am using a span instead of a link"

Why not just place the click event on the `<a href='whatever'>`?

```
  // Use the actual ID instead of 'a'.
$('a').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from being followed
    // do something
});
```

Then change the text-decoration of the `<a>` on using the pseudo `:hover`

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

If you do it on a `<span>` instead, the `:hover` won't work in IE6.

Comment: if you do this, what do you put in the href? or are you saying it doesn't matter because of hte event.PreventDefault() ??